# Mock UpdateResult From UpdateOne Using Go Mongo-Driver And mtest

Tags: mongodb, go, mocking, mongo-go, mongo-go-driver

I'm trying to use the `mtest` package (https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest) to perform some testing with mock results on my MongoDB calls, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly mock the `*mongo.UpdateResult` value that gets returned when you make an `UpdateOne(...)` call on a collection.

Here is a snippet demonstrating the problem:

```
package test

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest"
)

func UpdateOneCall(mongoClient *mongo.Client) error {
    filter := bson.D{{Key: "SomeIDField", Value: "SomeID"}}
    update := bson.D{{Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{{Key: "ANewField", Value: true}}}}
    collection := mongoClient.Database("SomeDatabase").Collection("SomeCollection")
    updateResult, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if updateResult.ModifiedCount != 1 {
        return errors.New("no field was updated")
    }
    return nil
}

func TestUpdateOneCall(t *testing.T) {
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    mt.Run("Successful Update", func(mt *mtest.T) {

        mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateSuccessResponse(
            bson.E{Key: "NModified", Value: 1},
            bson.E{Key: "N", Value: 1},
        ))

        err := UpdateOneCall(mt.Client)

        assert.Nil(t, err, "Should have successfully triggered update")
    })
}
```

The `collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update)` call works perfectly fine. There are no errors returned. Unfortunately, the `updateResult.ModifiedCount` value is always 0.

I've tried multiple combinations of `mtest.CreateSuccessResponse(...)` and `bson.D`, utilizing names such as `NModified` and `N` (as can be seen in the snippet), as well as `ModifiedCount` and `MatchedCount`. Nothing seems to do the trick.

Is there anyway to mock this call such that it actually returns a value for the `ModifiedCount`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mt.AddMockResponses(bson.D{
            {"ok", 1},
            {"nModified", 1},
        })
```

This worked for me to get ModifiedCount : 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The fact that it just came down to case-sensitivity makes me upset.  Good find! This was absolutely the solution. Just need to use `nModified` and `n` instead of `NModified` and `N`. Also, for anyone interested, you can still use the `mtest.CreateSuccessResponse` as well, so it can look like this:

`mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateSuccessResponse(bson.E{Key: "nModified", Value: 1},bson.E{Key: "n", Value: 1}))`

Answer (score 6):

@Vishwas Mallikarjuna got the right answer, so I'm leaving their post as the accepted one because they absolutely deserve that. However, given their findings, I just wanted to expand a little bit.

The issue came down to case-sensitivity. Now that I know that, I was able to mock the `MatchedCount`, `ModifiedCount`, `UpsertedCount`, and the `UpsertedID`.

This chunk of code shows how you would go about influencing all of these values:

```
package test

import (
    "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/operation"
)

const (
    mockMatchedCount            int64  = 5
    oneLessThanMockedMatchCount int64  = 4
    mockModifiedCount           int64  = 22
    mockUpsertedCount           int64  = 13
    mockUpsertedID              string = "CouldBeAnythingIThink"
)

func UpdateOneCall(mongoClient *mongo.Client) (*mongo.UpdateResult, error) {
    filter := bson.D{{Key: "SomeIDField", Value: "SomeID"}}
    update := bson.D{{Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{{Key: "ANewField", Value: true}}}}
    collection := mongoClient.Database("SomeDatabase").Collection("SomeCollection")
    return collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update)
}

func TestUpdateOneCall(t *testing.T) {
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    mt.Run("Successful Update", func(mt *mtest.T) {

        upsertedVals := make([]operation.Upsert, mockUpsertedCount)
        upsertedVals[0] = operation.Upsert{ID: mockUpsertedID}
        mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateSuccessResponse(
            bson.E{Key: "n", Value: mockMatchedCount},
            bson.E{Key: "nModified", Value: mockModifiedCount},
            bson.E{Key: "upserted", Value: upsertedVals},
        ))

        result, err := UpdateOneCall(mt.Client)

        assert.Nil(t, err, "Should have successfully triggered update")
        assert.Equal(t, result.MatchedCount, oneLessThanMockedMatchCount)
        assert.Equal(t, result.ModifiedCount, mockModifiedCount)
        assert.Equal(t, result.UpsertedCount, mockUpsertedCount)
        assert.Equal(t, result.UpsertedID, mockUpsertedID)
    })
}
```

Also, if you're wondering why the actual `result.MatchedCount` is `oneLessThanMockedMatchCount`, it comes down to how having an `Upserted` value works. If you go through the logic, in the file `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.10.2/mongo/collection.go` you'll find this chunk of code that explains it:

```
opRes := op.Result()
res := &UpdateResult{
    MatchedCount:  opRes.N,
    ModifiedCount: opRes.NModified,
    UpsertedCount: int64(len(opRes.Upserted)),
}
if len(opRes.Upserted) > 0 {
    res.UpsertedID = opRes.Upserted[0].ID
    res.MatchedCount--
}

return res, err
```